# cloudsql does not allow pglogical to be used with an external server?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am working on setting up a master/slave in cloud sql. I am following the docs from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-replication-from-external) to set it up.

My master db is hosted on an external server but its able to reach gcp via ipsec tunnels that is set. My problem is that my DB engine is postgresql and in order to use publication/subscription to enable sync between master/slave i need to use the pglogical module. I have set this on my external server. I can also set it in cloud sql by passing flags attribute as [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/instances#settings).

I pass it like this in the POST request to create it (my plan is to use the same method to create it with terraform after this setup)

```
"databaseFlags" : [
{
   "name": "cloudsql.enable_pglogical",
   "value": "on",
}
```

But I get the following error:

> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Value requested is not valid. Failed to set cloudsql.enable_pglogical: pglogical cannot be enabled while an instance is replicating from an external server",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "invalidFlagValue"
> }
> ]

By the error msg, it seems like i cannot enable pglogical if its replicating from an external server. I have checked that the flags work if the replication is not for an external server.

Is there anything else I can do here to overcome this?

Comment: I can see you posted question in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266363501#comment3) and an answer has given there, have you tried those suggestions?

Comment: well its not technically an answer that was given butI managed to find a solution by reverse engineering the whole thing and it was due to a dependency issue that breaks the replication.

Comment: Can you post your answer as a solution? So that, it will be useful for others who are facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting this with `postgres12` but using a shared docker volume that had another container with `postgres9.4` with `pglogical` setup on. Creating a new volume and starting up with a required instructions allow me to sort the replication.

I was able to trace this by looking at the postgres logs (set in `ERROR REPORTING AND LOGGING` in .conf). So even if your error varies, look for what the issue states and attempt a fresh setup.